# jQuery change event firing on all fields in angular directive only in IE9

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I have a directive to control range sliders on a search form.  It behaves as expected except in IE9.  When I update a field in IE9 it called the .change() function on all fields created by the directive even though they are specified.   Here is an abbreviated copy of the directive.

```
MyFactory.directive('rangeSlider', [ '$log', '$filter', function( $log, $filter ) {
    var sliderTemplate = "<div>" +
        "<div id='{{rangeData.slider}}'></div>" +
        "<input id='{{rangeData.lowerId}}' type='text' placeholder='No Min' class='text-center'>" +
        "<input id='{{rangeData.upperId}}' type='text' placeholder='No Max' class='text-center right'>" +
        "<div class='middle-marker'>to</div>" +
        "</div>";
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: sliderTemplate,
        scope: {
            saveRangeData: '&',
            values: '='
        },
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            var initialLowerValue, initialUpperValue;

            scope.rangeData = [];

            if (attrs.step) {
                scope.rangeData.step = parseFloat(attrs.step);
            } else {
                scope.rangeData.step = 1;
            }

            scope.rangeData.slider = attrs.slider;
            scope.rangeData.lowerId = attrs.lowerId;
            scope.rangeData.lowerRange = parseInt(attrs.lowerRange, 10) - scope.rangeData.step;
            scope.rangeData.upperId = attrs.upperId;
            scope.rangeData.upperRange = parseInt(attrs.upperRange, 10) + scope.rangeData.step;
            scope.rangeData.modelName = attrs.modelName;
            scope.rangeData.initialValues = scope.values;

            if ( (scope.rangeData.initialValues) && (scope.rangeData.initialValues[0]) != null ) {
                initialLowerValue = scope.rangeData.initialValues[0];
            } else {
                initialLowerValue = scope.rangeData.lowerRange;
            }

            if ( (scope.rangeData.initialValues) && (scope.rangeData.initialValues[1]) != null ) {
                initialUpperValue = scope.rangeData.initialValues[1];
            } else {
                initialUpperValue = scope.rangeData.upperRange;
            }

            function updateFields( ui ) {
                if( ui.values[ 0 ] > ui.values[ 1 ] ) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Sentinel value check, lower
                // Additional check prevents max upperRange value from being set if the user puts in a value out of range.
                if ( ui.values[ 0 ] === scope.rangeData.lowerRange || ui.values[ 0 ] === scope.rangeData.upperRange ) {
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.lowerId ).val('');
                    scope.rangeData.lowerVal = null;
                } else {
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.lowerId ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
                    scope.rangeData.lowerVal = ui.values[ 0 ];
                }

                // Sentinel value check, upper
                if ( ui.values[ 1 ] === scope.rangeData.upperRange ) {
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.upperId ).val('');
                    scope.rangeData.upperVal = null;
                } else {
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.upperId ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
                    scope.rangeData.upperVal = ui.values[ 1 ];
                }

                scope.saveRangeData({ rangeData: scope.rangeData });

            }

            scope.$watch( element, function(){
                $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider({
                    step: scope.rangeData.step,
                    range: true,
                    min: Number( scope.rangeData.lowerRange ),
                    max: Number( scope.rangeData.upperRange ),
                    values: [ Number( initialLowerValue ), Number( initialUpperValue ) ],
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {
                        updateFields(ui);
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        updateFields(ui);
                    }
                });

                // Ensures value of slider reflects against input fields initially
                $( "#" + scope.rangeData.lowerId ).val( $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider( "values", 0 ) );

                // Ensures placeholder functionality
                if ( initialLowerValue === scope.rangeData.lowerRange ) {
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.lowerId ).val('');
                }

                $( "#" + scope.rangeData.upperId ).val( $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

                // Ensures placeholder functionality
                if (initialUpperValue === scope.rangeData.upperRange) {
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.upperId ).val('');
                }

                // Ensures changes to input fields reflects against slider.
                $( "#" + scope.rangeData.lowerId ).change( function(){
                    var ui = { values: [] };
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider( "values", 0, unformatValue( $( "#" + scope.rangeData.lowerId ).val() ) );
                    ui.values = $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider( "values" );
                    updateFields( ui );
                });

                $( "#" + scope.rangeData.upperId ).change( function(){
                    var ui = { values: [] };
                    $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider( "values", 1, unformatValue( $( "#" + scope.rangeData.upperId ).val() ) );
                    ui.values = $( "#" + scope.rangeData.slider ).slider( "values" );
                    updateFields( ui );
                });

            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

I've tackled a similar problem before. Try the `click` event in IE, `change` for others.

Not sure why it works for me, I just chalked it up as another IE anomaly.

Comment: The difference is that I need it to fire as the user tabs out of a field, not when there is a specific click event.